# Plot a Horizontal lines between 7h00min (UTC) and now in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This is my first post ever hope it will be fine and respect the rules.
I have a problem on a pine script, I have some value that are calculated between hour X and Y. I want to extend lines to the live candle.[image: Description]

There is my script that currently draw lines.
`

```
eq = input.session(title='Eq Session', defval='0200-0300', group="Eq & Zone Session")
eq_session = is_new_session('1440', eq)
_eqstart = start_time(eq)

float _eqlow = na
float _eqhigh = na
float eqlow_f = na
float eqhigh_f = na
_eqline = line(na)
_plus_r1line = line(na)
_minus_r1line= line(na)
_plus_r2line = line(na)
_minus_r2line= line(na)
_plus_r3line = line(na)
_minus_r3line= line(na)

_eqlow := eq_session ? low : in_session(eq) ? math.min(low, _eqlow[1]) : na
_eqhigh := eq_session ? high : in_session(eq) ? math.max(high, _eqhigh[1]) : na
diffeq = _eqhigh[1] - _eqlow[1]


// R line
if in_session(eq)
    if in_session(eq)[1]
        line.delete(_eqline[1])
        line.delete(_plus_r1line[1])
        line.delete(_minus_r1line[1])
        line.delete(_plus_r2line[1])
        line.delete(_minus_r2line[1])
        line.delete(_plus_r3line[1])
        line.delete(_minus_r3line[1])

    eq_value =(_eqhigh+_eqlow)/2

    r2plus = 2.5*(_eqhigh-_eqlow)
    r2minus =  2.5*(_eqhigh-_eqlow)
    r3plus = 3.5*(_eqhigh-_eqlow)
    r3minus = 3.5*(_eqhigh-_eqlow)

    _eqline := line.new(_eqstart, eq_value, time, eq_value, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.fuchsia)
    _eqline


    _plus_r2line := line.new(_eqstart, eq_value+r2plus, time, eq_value+r2plus , xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.green)
    _plus_r2line
    _minus_r2line := line.new(_eqstart,eq_value-r2minus , time,eq_value-r2minus , xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.red)
    _minus_r2line

    _plus_r3line := line.new(_eqstart, eq_value+r3plus, time,eq_value+r3plus , xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.green)
    _plus_r3line
    _minus_r3line := line.new(_eqstart,eq_value-r3minus , time, eq_value-r3minus, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color = color.red)
    _minus_r3line
```

`

I tried to save my lines in sort of variables, create a new session type during my session day trade and plot on it, without success :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `var` line so you don't need to delete and create new lines all the time.

Your problem is, you need to update `x2` of your line when you are not in a session.

Here is a small example for you that keeps track of the session high.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

session_time = input.session("0200-0300", "Session")

in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time + ":1234567")
is_new_session = not in_session[1] and in_session
is_session_end = in_session[1] and not in_session

var float session_high = na
var line session_high_line = na

session_start_idx = ta.barssince(is_new_session)
session_high := is_new_session ? high : in_session ? (high > session_high) ? high : session_high : session_high // Update session high price

if (is_session_end)
    session_high_line := line.new(bar_index - session_start_idx, session_high, bar_index, session_high, color=color.green, width=2)
else if (not in_session)
    line.set_x2(session_high_line, bar_index)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot I could do it with your help ! Thank you so much !!!